# Creating a folder in php apache

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, yii, mkdir

Here is my code to create a folder named images

```
$path="".Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/users/".Yii::app()->session["id"]."/images";
        if(!file_exists($path))
        {
            mkdir($path,0777,true);
            echo($path);
        }
```

But the error i am having is

```
mkdir(): Permission denied (/var/www/yiicapp/protected/models/Statement.php:123)
```

I am logged in as "bhawin" but it is making owner `www-data`

Comment: because you don't have permission to write anything at `/images`

Answer (score 1):

You've got no right to write to given folder and PHP can't change it. You have to use SSH or FTP with user with permissions and change rights to 777.

Comment: `www-data` is server user and he should be owner of files or at least got 777 rights on folders.

Comment: what will happen if i change this to my name in httpd.conf

Comment: @BhawinParkeria You shouldn't do that. Server should have separated user.

Comment: okk but when i try mkdir with php , why it gives permission denied , do i have to add myself in www-data group ?

Answer (score 1):

`Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` it is domain path URL such as `http://example.com/yourfolderpath` instead of that you can use **relative path** of the folder like /var/www/.....

Answer (score 0):

http://pt1.php.net/chmod

You have no rights to create a new folder, so chmod is probably what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

`Yii::app()->request->baseUrl` is a URL, not a local filesystem path. You cannot create directories in a URL.

To work with the filesystem you would need to start from `Yii::app()->basePath` instead, although putting user-supplied content in a web-accessible location might not be smart (everyone can view that content if they know the correct URL). Depending on what the content is the correct approach might be to put it outside the web server document root entirely.